# ASM help - un-match block setting

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

Write a program that calculate the sum of values in a given array using ArraySum Sub procedure.
Array DWORD 8, 3, 12, 9, 2, 20, 15, 6, 5
- Name the subroutine as ArraySumProc.
- Pass above defined array and size of the array to the subroutine ArraySum.
- To access the values in the caller frame, use EBP (remember EBP is created at the callee side).
- The calculated sum result needs to be assigned to val1 memory variable at the caller side.
- The calculated expression result needs to be displayed on console screen from main subroutine.
- Use the appropriate registers and loop instruction.
- Run your program using the debugger to verify your answers.
▪ Use Step Into instead of Step Over to keep track of the stack, ESP, EBP, EIP during debugging.
▪ To access the stack memory, copy the value of ESP from the register window and past it in the search text box in the memory window.

I have entered data and code section but somehow there is an error. Anybody knows why??

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
    array DWORD 8, 3, 12, 9, 2, 20, 15, 6, 5
    theSum DWORD?

.code
    mov esi,OFFSET array
    mov ecx,LENGTHOF array
    call ArraySum
    mov theSum,eax
INVOKE ExitProcess,0
main ENDP

ArraySum PROC
    push esi
    push ecx
    mov eax,0
L1: add eax,[esi]
    add esi,TYPE DWORD
    loop L1
    pop ecx
    pop esi
    ret
ArraySum ENDP
END main
```

Errors:
1>AddTwo.asm(9): error A2008: syntax error : theSum
1>AddTwo.asm(17): fatal error A1010: unmatched block nesting : main

Comment: I think the way you have `main ENDP` defined is suspect.  I'd expect a different identifier after the label.  I'd expect a `main proc` instead - or perhaps you forgot to define it after your `.code` label?

Comment: The first error may be the lack of a space between `DWORD` and `?`.